How to configure access to remote Interbase Database in emsserver.ini for Rad Server
I have searched and I found this question: Hosting RAD Server in IIS. EMS license not found
which is the error I am receiving.  I have tried the solutions listed there, but I am still receiving the license not found issue.
The server at 192.168.2.28 holds a Rad Server and Interbase running a production web app and is properly licensed and works fine.
We are attempting to spin up another server (currently for testing and maybe eventually for load balancing) and connect to the interbase db on 192.168.2.28.
The Data section of the emsserver.ini file on the new server looks like this:
InstanceName:192.168.2.28/gds_db
Database=C:\Users\Public\Documents\Embarcadero\EMS\emsserver1.ib
UserName=TheUerName
Password=ThePassword

As I mentioned, when I attempt to connect to this new server via Postman, I received the error:
"EMS license not found.  To resolve this issue, install an instance of Interbase with an EMS license and configure emsserver.ini to connect to the licensed instance."

As far as I can tell by reading the other post, I have this file configured correctly.  We are using Delphi 10.3.1.
One question is, is my InstanceName configured correctly?  The IP address is correct and gds_db appears to be the instance name running on 192.168.2.28.
Another question is, Do I need the emsserver1.ib file to also be located on my new server?  Shouldn't it just exist on 192.168.2.28.
If it only needs to exist on 192.168.2.28, why do I need to specify the full path name to the file in the emsserver.ini on the new server?   Should I specify the Database property differently somehow?
Do I just have the emsserver.ini file configured incorrectly?  Do I need to make some change on 192.168.2.28 to allow this to work?
Thank you for any help you can provide.
Ken

Have you tried just using gds_db as the instance name?  You can name your instance during the Interbase install, and if you didn't, gds_db is the default. Did you obtain your production license from Embarcadero sales?

HI @JohnEasley the gds_gb doesn't exist on the same machine I am trying to run Rad Server on. It is on another machine running Ran Server.  So, somehow I have to specify the server and the instance.  That other Rad Server is properly licensed with a site license.  My understand was the InnoDatabase held the license.  Does it not?

I think you need a license on your 64 bit server. And yes, I think the license key gets stored in your local Interbase instance.

I was able to get this going.  I was really close before posting but I found out that I was using the wrong file name for the DB.
The correct configuration is
Database=/3050:
in my case it was
Database=192.168.1.5/3050:C:\Users\Public\Documents\Embarcadero\EMS\emsserver1.ib
